# I want to create a SELECT with Max

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I created a code for select with max, but I get an error: using `ORDER BY DESC`, but I would like `SELECT()` with `MAX()`

DATA= Field Name
CMV= Table Name (ACCESS)

```
Set banco = New ADODB.Recordset
'DEFININDO INSTRUÇÃO A VARIÁVEL
sql = " SELECT MAX(DATA) FROM CMV"
sql = sql & " WHERE DEPOSITANTE= '" & nDEPOSITANTE & "'"

'CONECTAR AO BANCO DE DADOS
cx.Conectar
    
'EXECUTAR A SQL
On Error Resume Next
banco.Open sql, cx.Conn

nDATA3 = banco.Fields("DATA")
        
'DESCONECTAR PARA LIBERAR MEMÓRIA
cx.Desconectar
```

Comment: Can you post the error message you receive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your error is attempting to access the column MAX(DATA) as Fields("Data"), you have to give it an alias like:

```
SELECT MAX(DATA) as MAX_DATA
...
```

and then refer to it by this name

```
 nDATA3 = banco.Fields("MAX_DATA")
```

Try this, but, honestly, your error might be somewhere else and hidden because 1. you are using ON ERROR RESUME NEXT, which would hide the error, and 2. you are not telling us where it fails and what the error is.

Comment: Sorry, I was very busy, and I didn't try your suggestions, but it works, Tks a lot